# Problems with starting Virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I try to start the Virtualbox, this are my steps

```
vagrant box add jhcook/osx-yosemite-10.10
mkdir test
cd test
vagrant init jhcook/osx-yosemite-10.10
```

modify the vagrant file like this:

```
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
# Don't boot with headless mode
vb.gui = true
vb.cpus = 2

# Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--graphicscontroller", "vboxvga"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--accelerate3d", "on"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ioapic", "on"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "128"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "on"]
```

end

and than I get

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'jhcook/osx-yosemite-10.10'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'jhcook/osx-yosemite-10.10' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: VagrantTest_default_1428936332822_32428
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'gurumeditation' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

I try different version of the Virtualbox and searching for answers in the internet. But I really don't see my mistake, I would be happy if somebody could help me  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue is about VirtualBox, not about Vagrant.

According to this article - http://www.macbreaker.com/2015/01/virtualbox-yosemite-zone.html :

> If your version of Virtualbox asks you to choose between 64-bit and 32-bit, be sure to choose 64-bit. Choosing 32-bit will result in a critical "Guru Meditation" error later on.

May be this is your case too? What if you will try install Yosemite by using mentioned article without Vagrant?

Comment: So, I don't using Windows, I am using Mac and Yosemite. I try this tutorial http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/getting-started-vagrant-os-osx-10-9-mavericks/ . A friend try it out as well and it works perfect on his mac. I also try different version of virtualbox the 4.3.26 and now the 4.2.28. This time I have a different exception

Comment: Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

Comment: Could you please to use VirtualBox GUI to be sure that your virtual machine is working? You can try to run your VM from there. We need to clarify is this problem related to the `vagrant`.

Comment: I used the GUI and it is still the same problem, it stopped and give me an error

Comment: In my case I just ran again `init.bat` in Windows. Edited again the `Homestead.yaml` file and then I ran `vagrant up --provision` and it just simply worked!